# Half of my laptop screen has suddenly gone dim

Tags: windows-8.1, lenovo-laptop, laptop-display

Issue:

[image: ScreenImage]

Solutions tried:

- Restart
- Updated some drivers as suggested by some blog posts on the internet

Nothing has worked so far. Can you please let me know what could be the issue?

Specs:
Lenovo G50-70 ideapad Windows 8.1

Comment: It’s a little hard to tell from the photo, but is there any noticeable gradient in the dimming or is it just that the right half is darker?

Comment: Try a linux live disk and see if the problem exists there.

Comment: Try entering the BIOS - that machine is late enough that the BIOS may be full-screen and you might be able to see the effect there. If you can see it in the BIOS, or when booting something else (like Linux), then it's possible you've had a backlight failure.

Comment: @DanielB No gradient. Just the right half is darker. Few days ago, only the top right corner of the screen was dark and i was able to fix it just by turning off the monitor (just the monitor) and turning it back on. But now nothing is working.

Comment: So as noted in my answer: screen or cable reseating.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes even in the BIOS setup screen half the screen is dim. I am facing this issue since the past 2 weeks. But till now it used to get resolved after restart or by turning off the monitor and turning it back on. That's why it seemed like a software issue.

Comment: If half screen in BIOS, it is not likely an operating software issue.

Comment: @Foos - Yea, that's a backlight issue, either there is a connector issue preventing power/control signals getting to the backlight, or the backlight module itself is going bad. You've got hardware problems, I'm afraid, and it's not likely to get better on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already updated the correct video (and possibly BIOS) driver, then substitute an external screen.

If the external screen works (likely with a good video driver), then check the screen connector (reseat) and then replace the screen if all the above fails.

If you can get a complete Lid replacement (screen, backlight, one end of the connecting cable properly installed), that is often the best way forward